# Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add design library but I get this error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for -
>
> ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:design:28.0.0.
>
> gradle: implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: have you added `google()` to your main gradle?

Comment: @KaranMer Yes and I checked my connection...still not working!

Comment: Post more of the log. It says where it looked either above or below that message.

Comment: The details of where it looked come after, starts with: `Searched in the following locations:`

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to "File".

2- Click on Invalidate Cache/ Restart.

3- Again click on Invalidate Cache / Restart(On dialoge window).

Let the gradle build without any interruption.

Hope this will help.